# How to have `e2fsck` use `-E discard` by default?

Tags: vmware, fsck

I want to run `e2fsck` with the arguments `-E discard` by default, eg when I create a `/forcefsck` or if the machine wasn't shutdown cleanly.

(I'm trying to stop my VMware guest's `*.vmdk` files growing constantly)

How do I give default options to `e2fsck`?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking about, but you can always use an alias...

```
alias e2fsck='e2fsck -E discard'
```

Comment: This won't work in the `touch /forcefsck` or dirty filesystem at boot time case.